# Autofac with azure mobile app

Tags: c#, azure, autofac, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to use autofac with azure mobile app to have dependency injection in custom controllers.

following this link

http://wp.sjkp.dk/dependency-injection-with-azure-mobile-services-net-backend/

however, i can't find ConfigBuilder, ConfigOptions classes in my project to get started.

Are they outdated or i am missing something here?

Update:

Managed to write a detailed explaination here about mobile app and autofac integration here.
https://cloudontopblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/18/18/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile Services is no longer active.  You are using Azure Mobile Apps.  That blog post is out of date at this point.

I don't know of anyone using AutoFac with Azure Mobile Apps, so I'm afraid you are blazing new trails.  If you get it figured out, please write about your experience!

Comment: did manage to write something finally.

hopefully this helps. someone viewing this.
https://cloudontopblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/18/18/